# Extremely slow query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

Below is a query which takes 30+ seconds to run. Based on similar queries I have running, I can't see where the hold up is here. My only thought is joining the job user id to job_applicants user id, but they need to be mapped.

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.user_id, u.first_name, u.last_name FROM users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN employee_access ea ON ea.user_id = u.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN confirmation c ON c.user_id = u.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN job_applicants a ON a.user_id = u.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN job j ON j.job_id = a.job_id
WHERE ea.access_id = 4 OR c.access_id = 4 OR (a.process_level = 0 AND j.access_id = 4) 
ORDER BY u.last_name asc
```

Comment: How large are your tables?  How are they indexed?

Comment: Can you also post the EXPLAIN of the query. (Simply put "EXPLAIN " in front of the select and run the query)

Comment: is `user_id` the primary-key in all these tables? if not, is it indexed ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `exists`:

```
select u.*
from users u
where exists (select 1
              from employee_access ea 
              where ea.user_id = u.user_id and ea.access_id = 4
             ) or
      exists (select 1
              from confirmation c 
              where c.user_id = u.user_id and c.access_id = 4
             ) or
      exists (select 1
              from job_applicants a join
                   job j 
                   on j.job_id = a.job_id
              where a.user_id = u.user_id and
                    a.process_level = 0 AND j.access_id = 4
             )
order by u.last_name;
```

This will prevent all the Cartesian products and the final removal of duplicates.

I would recommend indexes on:

- `users(last_name, user_id)`
- `employee_access(user_id, access_id)`
- `confirmation(user_id, access_id)`
- `job_applicants(user_id, process_level, job_id)`
- `job(job_id, access_id)`

Comment: After seeing your answer, I now understand why the original query uses outer join -- it needs to handle the ID only matching in one of the other tables.

Comment: Without updating indexes, this updated query shaved off 20 seconds (8 vs 28). Thank you! Will leave a comment on speed once updated indexes are in place.

Comment: For `job_applicants` I'd use the index `(user_id, process_level, job_id)` since you first want to filter by `process_level` before you join with the next table using `job_id`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel . . . Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another approach.  This has the advantage of *first* gathering the list of `user_ids`, *then* reaching into `users` for the other columns:

```
SELECT  u.user_id, u.first_name, u.last_name
    FROM  users u
    JOIN (
        ( SELECT user_id FROM employee_access WHERE access_id = 4 )
        UNION DISTINCT
        ( SELECT user_id FROM confirmation    WHERE access_id = 4 )
        UNION DISTINCT
        ( SELECT a.user_id 
              FROM job_applicants a 
              JOIN job j  USING(job_id)
              WHERE a.process_level = 0
                AND j.access_id = 4 )
    ) AS x USING(user_id)
    ORDER BY u.last_name ASC
```

Indexes:

```
employee_access: INDEX(access_id, user_id)  -- (covering)
confirmation:    INDEX(access_id, user_id)  -- (covering)
job:             INDEX(access_id, job_id)  -- (covering)
job_applicants:  INDEX(process_level, job_id, user_id)  -- (covering)
users:  PRIMARY KEY(user_id)
```

See if this will shave off most of the remaining 8 seconds.

Comment: Indeed it did. This is quick!

Answer (score 1):

This should work. It is similar in concept to Gordon's answer *but I have a borderline pathological distrust of correlated subqueries*.

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.user_id, u.first_name, u.last_name 
FROM users u
WHERE u.user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM employee_access WHERE access_id = 4)
   OR u.user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM confirmation WHERE access_id = 4)
   OR u.user_id IN (
        SELECT a.user_id 
        FROM job_applicants a 
        INNER JOIN job j ON j.job_id = a.job_id
        WHERE a.process_level = 0 AND j.access_id = 4
      )
ORDER BY u.last_name asc
```